# where does ${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir} resolve to on BigInsights on cloud?

Tags: log4j, ibm-cloud, spark-streaming, biginsights

I'm trying to configure spark streaming logging.  The spark [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application) state to set the following property:

```
log4j.appender.file_appender=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark.log
```

Where does `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` point to on a BigInsights on Cloud 4.2 Basic cluster?